# exponential generating function of $n^n$

Tags: generating-functions

Question is simple:
What's the EGF of $n^n$? I would also like to know the regular generating function too, but the first is a priority.

Standard operations on GF's have failed to yield adequate results with me

Comment: This is pretty close https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions ... integrate this ?

Comment: It's related to the Lambert W-function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an offset of $1 $, the EGF is
$$1-e^{W(-x)}$$ where $W(.) is the principal branch of Lambert function.